# ¿Se puede quitar la reactividad de un elemento en vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy usando vuejs para crear un formulario que almacene los datos en un array. Mi problema es que al momento de realizar un cambio, éste se ve reflejado en las "copias" que existan. Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de quitar esta caracteristicas de vuejs de ser reactivo, pero solo en un elemento en concreto. Por ejemplo si tengo my array definido en el data:

```
miArreglo =[]
otroArreglo = []
```

Luego en una funcion hago lo siguiente:

```
funcionCualquiera () {
 this.otroArreglo = miArreglo.push()
}
```

Si en algún momento borrara lo que hay en `miArreglo`, tambien se borraría la "copia" guardada en  `otroArreglo`. Existe alguna forma para evitar esto?

Comment: Puedes usar slice como te comentaba @giabanchi o puedes hacer uso del spread operator o puedes hacer un JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(miArreglo)) con eso no modificarias el arreglo inicial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no queres eliminar la reactividad de VUE. **NUNCA**. Lo que queres hacer, es que esos dos array sean copias entre si, por lo menos al principio, pero no el mismo array.

Al hacer

```
this.otroArreglo = miArreglo.push()
```

Le estas diciendo que otroArreglo es el mismo array que miArreglo, porque lo que se guarda en esas variables es la referencia al array, y no el contenido del mismo.

si queres copiar miArreglo a otroArreglo, lo que tenes que hacer es

```
this.otroArreglo = miArreglo.slice()
```

Que lo que va a hacer es copiar el contenido de un array en otro array, y van a ser array diferentes.

---

**NOTA**

en realidad miArreglo.push() devuelve la longitud del nuevo arreglo, asi que supongo que eso fue un fallo al copiar tu codigo.

Comment: incluso puede hacer `this.otroArreglo =  [...miArreglo];` tambien existe  `this.otroArreglo  = Array.from(miArreglo);  `

Comment: Gracias amigo me salvaste.